# Iterating creating range per months

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration

I am working with python 3.7 under the windows 10 environment.

I want to create a range but instead that jumps from year to year (like the piece of code below), it should jump month per month.  I did not know how to adapt this to make it work

I need to scan over daily data that is divided into months:

```
# Creating the date range for each year during each iteration
        start = str(yr) + '-01-01'
        end = str(yr) + '-12-31'
        d_range = pd.date_range(start = start, 
                                end = end, 
                                freq = 'D')
```

With this loop, I get an index that goes from 1 to 365.

```
1
2
3
4
..
365
```

This index was made with the intention to create one value per day corresponds to a yearly data.  However, I don't have year data, I have monthly data. I would like to iterate to create an index that instead of going from 1-365 goes from 1-31 for January and then starts again and creates 1-28 for February, and so on until December.

The output data should be and index that goes like:

```
1
2
3
4
..
31
1
2
3
4
..
28
1
2
3
..
31
.....
until dic 31
```

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: What do you mean by year to year or month to month? If you use `freq='M'` it will give you the date range with the last of each month between your `start` and `end`. Is that what you are expecting?